# Serial keys: What to do?

Tags: java

I've been reading some posts here and articles around the web but I can't picture a serial keys based system for my application.

http://www.brandonstaggs.com/2007/07/26/implementing-a-partial-serial-number-verification-system-in-delphi/

I read this one but I can't turn the code into Java and I'm not very familiar with the terms either.

What possible insight can you give me on this? Ideally my application will be for sale but I don't expect it to be much popular, I don't mind much if it gets cracked if I have users that appreciate the product and buy it, but I want to avoid it to be easily cracked. Please be as specific as you can, I'm somewhat new to Java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not that hard, if you're somewhat flexible in your requirements -- perhaps the scheme below would work for you.

You could just produce K = [SN, H([X,SN,Y])] which is the concatenation of an incrementing serial number with a hash, where the hash is a secure hash function of the concatenation of the serial number between unique constants X and Y that are secret ["salt" you use to prevent the use of rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table#Defense_against_rainbow_tables).

Use a well-known secure hash algorithm (e.g. SHA-1 or SHA-2; MD5 is probably also adequate, since the known weaknesses for MD5 are collision attacks, and *not* [preimage attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack)) and you should be all set, as least as far as the serial key part goes (you'll probably want to prevent two people from using the same key).

The other thing you can do which is helpful is use K = [SN, T, H([X, SN, T, Y])] -- use both the serial number and a timestamp. This can be used to allow only a narrow use window for the serial key: it's valid within N seconds of the timestamp, so it would prevent reuse of the key outside that window.

Then encode/decode K to a representation that can be used to easily allow users to enter the key (e.g. base64).

It's best to have a simple and transparent overall algorithm -- obfuscation is not going to help you if someone reverse-engineers your scheme.

Answer (score 13):

I was quite interested in that article, so I implemented the code in Java. may be of use

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class KeyValidator {
    private static final byte[][] params = new byte[][] { { 24, 4, 127 }, { 10, 0, 56 }, { 1, 2, 91 }, { 7, 1, 100 } };
    private static final Set<String> blacklist = new TreeSet<String>();

    static {
        blacklist.add("11111111");
    }

    private static byte PKV_GetKeyByte(final int seed, final byte a, final byte b, final byte c) {
        final int a1 = a % 25;
        final int b1 = b % 3;
        if (a1 % 2 == 0) {
            return (byte) (((seed >> a1) & 0x000000FF) ^ ((seed >> b1) | c));
        } else {
            return (byte) (((seed >> a1) & 0x000000FF) ^ ((seed >> b1) & c));
        }
    }

    private static String PKV_GetChecksum(final String s) {
        int left = 0x0056;
        int right = 0x00AF;
        for (byte b : s.getBytes()) {
            right += b;
            if (right > 0x00FF) {
                right -= 0x00FF;
            }
            left += right;
            if (left > 0x00FF) {
                left -= 0x00FF;
            }
        }
        int sum = (left << 8) + right;
        return intToHex(sum, 4);
    }

    public static String PKV_MakeKey(final int seed) {
        // Fill KeyBytes with values derived from Seed.
        // The parameters used here must be exactly the same
        // as the ones used in the PKV_CheckKey function.
        // A real key system should use more than four bytes.
        final byte[] keyBytes = new byte[4];
        keyBytes[0] = PKV_GetKeyByte(seed, params[0][0], params[0][1], params[0][2]);
        keyBytes[1] = PKV_GetKeyByte(seed, params[1][0], params[1][1], params[1][2]);
        keyBytes[2] = PKV_GetKeyByte(seed, params[2][0], params[2][1], params[2][2]);
        keyBytes[3] = PKV_GetKeyByte(seed, params[3][0], params[3][1], params[3][2]);

        // the key string begins with a hexadecimal string of the seed
        final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(intToHex(seed, 8));

        // then is followed by hexadecimal strings of each byte in the key
        for (byte b : keyBytes) {
            result.append(intToHex(b, 2));
        }

        // add checksum to key string
        result.append(PKV_GetChecksum(result.toString()));

        final String key = result.toString();
        return key.substring(0, 4) + "-" + key.substring(4, 8) + "-" + key.substring(8, 12) + "-" + key.substring(12, 16) + "-" + key.substring(16, 20);
    }

    private static boolean PKV_CheckKeyChecksum(final String key) {
        // remove cosmetic hyphens and normalise case
        final String comp = key.replaceAll("-", "").toLowerCase(Locale.UK);
        if (comp.length() != 20) {
            return false; // Our keys are always 20 characters long
        }

        // last four characters are the checksum
        final String checksum = comp.substring(16);
        return checksum.equals(PKV_GetChecksum(comp.substring(0, 16)));
    }

    public static Status PKV_CheckKey(final String key) {
        if (!PKV_CheckKeyChecksum(key)) {
            return Status.KEY_INVALID; // bad checksum or wrong number of
            // characters
        }

        // remove cosmetic hyphens and normalise case
        final String comp = key.replaceAll("-", "").toLowerCase(Locale.UK);

        // test against blacklist
        for (String bl : blacklist) {
            if (comp.startsWith(bl)) {
                return Status.KEY_BLACKLISTED;
            }
        }

        // At this point, the key is either valid or forged,
        // because a forged key can have a valid checksum.
        // We now test the "bytes" of the key to determine if it is
        // actually valid.

        // When building your release application, use conditional defines
        // or comment out most of the byte checks! This is the heart
        // of the partial key verification system. By not compiling in
        // each check, there is no way for someone to build a keygen that
        // will produce valid keys. If an invalid keygen is released, you
        // simply change which byte checks are compiled in, and any serial
        // number built with the fake keygen no longer works.

        // Note that the parameters used for PKV_GetKeyByte calls MUST
        // MATCH the values that PKV_MakeKey uses to make the key in the
        // first place!

        // extract the Seed from the supplied key string
        final int seed;
        try {
            seed = Integer.valueOf(comp.substring(0, 8), 16);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return Status.KEY_PHONY;
        }

        // test key 0
        final String kb0 = comp.substring(8, 10);
        final byte b0 = PKV_GetKeyByte(seed, params[0][0], params[0][1], params[0][2]);
        if (!kb0.equals(intToHex(b0, 2))) {
            return Status.KEY_PHONY;
        }

        // test key1
        final String kb1 = comp.substring(10, 12);
        final byte b1 = PKV_GetKeyByte(seed, params[1][0], params[1][1], params[1][2]);
        if (!kb1.equals(intToHex(b1, 2))) {
            return Status.KEY_PHONY;
        }

        // test key2
        final String kb2 = comp.substring(12, 14);
        final byte b2 = PKV_GetKeyByte(seed, params[2][0], params[2][1], params[2][2]);
        if (!kb2.equals(intToHex(b2, 2))) {
            return Status.KEY_PHONY;
        }

        // test key3
        final String kb3 = comp.substring(14, 16);
        final byte b3 = PKV_GetKeyByte(seed, params[3][0], params[3][1], params[3][2]);
        if (!kb3.equals(intToHex(b3, 2))) {
            return Status.KEY_PHONY;
        }

        // If we get this far, then it means the key is either good, or was made
        // with a keygen derived from "this" release.
        return Status.KEY_GOOD;
    }

    protected static String intToHex(final Number n, final int chars) {
        return String.format("%0" + chars + "x", n);
    }

    public enum Status {
        KEY_GOOD, KEY_INVALID, KEY_BLACKLISTED, KEY_PHONY
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be delighted if you show how to implement it.

Answer (score 4):

Securing applications in general isn't a simple task. A lot of companies are investing a lot of money to find new securing algorithms, which get all cracked very fast.

Securing Java applications is a bit more difficult. Any serial verification algorithm embedded within your application can be decompiled, so a serial key generator will be pretty easy to build.

A good starting point is the article you gave. It tells you how to build a key verification system, and how to generate keys for your (legitimate) users.

After implementing such an algorithm, I'd suggest you to secure the source code a little, so decompilation become a little more "tricky". Use code obfuscation techniques to hide your verification algorithm implementation. This will also make the task harder for people trying to crack your application just by modifying byte-code.

A good technique could be to export your key verification algorithm on a remote server. The client send the key to the server, which replies with a 'validation code' to tell your application that your key is valid. But this doesn't prevents users from modifying your application to remove any key verification procedure. And this might be very annoying for legitimate users who don't have a 24-hours Internet connection. I'm thinking about Steam, which verify the key validity at every launch on Internet, and which annoys a lot of users.

To find a good protection technique, look around you and try to determine how others people do, which techniques are working, which aren't. They are a lot of example (Video game industry, in particular). But keep in mind that even the best companies aren't able to secure their applications correctly. No techniques are unbreakable.

Comment: I wish I could mark both as an answer but Jason's answer gave me something to start working on so I'll mark his answer for the purposes of my question. Thanks!